# Search bar in UITableView for Realm objects

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, realm

I have a table view populated by Realm Objects, and when i click on a cell, it takes me to another view that shows me more information about that Object. I want to add a search bar for this table view to check for the objects' "fullName" property. I know how to add a search bar for an array of strings, but I haven't found any tutorial or guidance on how to do it using Swift 2.0. Any help please?

EDIT: That's how i'm populating my tableview

```
var dataSource : Results<Patient>!

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let identifier: String = "myCell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier)

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }

    let currentPatientInfo = dataSource[indexPath.section]

    cell?.textLabel?.text = currentPatientInfo
    cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DetailDisclosureButton

    return cell!

}
```

I have the data in sections, not rows

EDIT: I added `RealmSwiftSearchController` to my project but occasionally i get this error when i click on a cell :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and it points to this code :

```
extension RealmSearchViewController {


 public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

// The line below
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Object
// Line ends
        self.resultsDelegate.searchViewController(self, willSelectObject: object, atIndexPath: indexPath)

        return indexPath
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open-source component called `RealmSearchViewController` that should be able to take care of pretty much all of the boilerplate code necessary with setting up a searchable `UITableView` as well as interoperating it with Realm: https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmSearchViewController

Additionally, there's a tutorial on how to implement it available on the Realm website: https://realm.io/news/building-an-ios-search-controller-in-swift/

Comment: I tried that, and when i'm populating my table view with the objects, only the first row shows the Patient's name, and i can click on it, but the other rows are blank, and whenever i click on them, it crashes by telling me > fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value ... and it points to ...

Comment: `extension RealmSearchViewController {
        public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
         /*!*/   let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Object /*!*/
            
            self.resultsDelegate.searchViewController(self, willSelectObject: object, atIndexPath: indexPath)
            
            return indexPath
        }`

Comment: Ok so i switched between the sections and the rows and the data appeared. However, no matter what i search, i either get the first row only, or blank (clickable and give me the same error) rows